# Find checked out files and users in SVN

Tags: visual-studio-2008, svn

How to find the list of user checked out and what are all the files are checked out on SVN as like VSS "Status Search".

I'm using Visual studio 2008 and it was integrated with SVN by AnkhSvn.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** svn does not operate that way.

**Less-short-but-not-long answer:** You may be able to extract something meaningful from svn served up via Apache, but the nature of svn does not place importance on who has what checked out, the important part is the commit and you can do many things with [hooks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).

Answer (score 2):

As SleighBoy already sad SVN does not provide this information.

You could use [locks](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.2/svn.advanced.locking.html) to use a resource **exclusively** and query the status of the resource. But **locks** are optional and can be broken.

```
$ svn help lock
lock: Lock working copy paths or URLs in the repository, so that
no other user can commit changes to them.
usage: lock TARGET...

$ svn help status
status (stat, st): Print the status of working copy files and directories.
usage: status [PATH...]
 'K' locked in repository, lock toKen present
```